# Mysql. Left joint with count not working

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.  takeoffheaders is as it name suggests the header table and takeoffitems is the items table.

Some of the header records do not have any related item records.  I need  to get a count of the related item records.

When I run this code I get 23 records back.

```
   SELECT
        takeoffheaders.Estimate_description
    FROM
        takeoffheaders 
    WHERE
        TakeOffHeaders.CostCodeguid = '{026F8AEE-0ADA-4DD0-8826-0B0C3BDB15EC}'
        and takeoffheaders.Job_Guid = '{FECD00C7-8C16-4D49-AC6A-DE5D5698219A}'
```

When I run this code I only get 8 records back.

```
Select  
    takeoffheaders.Estimate_description,
    count( takeoffitems.Estimate_guid ) AS COUNT
FROM
    takeoffheaders 
    LEFT JOIN takeoffitems 
    ON takeoffheaders.Estimate_guid = takeoffitems.Estimate_guid
    AND takeoffheaders.Client_Guid = takeoffitems.Client_Guid
WHERE
    TakeOffHeaders.CostCodeguid = '{026F8AEE-0ADA-4DD0-8826-0B0C3BDB15EC}'
 and takeoffheaders.Job_Guid = '{FECD00C7-8C16-4D49-AC6A-DE5D5698219A}'
GROUP BY
    takeoffitems.Estimate_guid
```

other than the join and count they are identical.  If I change

```
count( takeoffitems.Estimate_guid ) AS COUNT

to 

takeoffitems.Estimate_guid
```

It makes no difference as expected.

Edit.

When I delete one of the header records that does not have any items, I still only get back 8 records and I a different  zero record.

Edit 2.

I only get back 8 records in the join but I only ever get one record with a zero count....

Edit 3

here are the records returned by the respective querys

[image]
Only 21 records now due to changes in the DB

[image]

Comment: Move `TakeOffHeaders.CostCodeguid = '{026F8AEE-0ADA-4DD0-8826-0B0C3BDB15EC}'
 and takeoffheaders.Job_Guid = '{FECD00C7-8C16-4D49-AC6A-DE5D5698219A}'` to your JOIN condition, instead of WHERE.

Comment: @ fg78nc   this only changes which one of the header records with no items comes back.  There are still only 8 records.

Comment: How many do you expect?

Comment: @ fg78nc.   I expect 23 records back from either query.  The query intent  of the join query  a list of header records with a count of the related item records.   The funny thing is that if you look at the edit I made...  I always get back 8 records with the join.  If I delete one of the header records that has no items, I still get back 8 records, just with a different header record with no items.

Comment: Please post your 23 row output.

Comment: `count(*)` instead of `count(takeoffitems.Estimate_guid)` which will not count null values; or `count(takeoffheaders.Estimate_guid)`  If the join conditions fail the value of items.estimate_guid will be null.  Nulls don't get counted.  So either `count(*)` or count from the table returning all records (takeoffheaders)  Since takeoffheaders could hav ea null estimate_Guid.   I think `count(*)` is closer to comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @ xQbert...  this does not work.  It still returns 8 rows but the count on Empty Task 2 is now 14 which is wrong.  It has zero records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by is on a table not in the select (at least one that's not aggregated)

```
SELECT takeoffheaders.Estimate_description
     , count( takeoffitems.Estimate_guid ) AS COUNT
FROM takeoffheaders 
LEFT JOIN takeoffitems 
  ON takeoffheaders.Estimate_guid = takeoffitems.Estimate_guid
 AND takeoffheaders.Client_Guid = takeoffitems.Client_Guid
WHERE TakeOffHeaders.CostCodeguid = '{026F8AEE-0ADA-4DD0-8826-0B0C3BDB15EC}'
  and Takeoffheaders.Job_Guid = '{FECD00C7-8C16-4D49-AC6A-DE5D5698219A}'
GROUP BY --takeoffitems.Estimate_guid  --not this one
         takeoffheaders.Estimate_guid  --this one
```

Comment: Still returns only 8 records.    for empty task 2 is    0, 14,14  .   A left

Comment: Just noticed your group by is on the wrong table.  should be on the same table as in the select.

Comment: That was it xQbert.  Thanks.